# TFS Build Script Tracing

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, build-script

When debugging a build script, is it possible to get TFS to use a build script that is currently checked out?

For example, I currently have a build script that I'm trying to debug, but in order to add a line of trace, I need to book out the TFSBuild.proj, change it, and then book it back in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to let the build server use the modified script, you need to check it in. But you can also consider to do a desktop build, which starts the build on your local system: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181723(VS.80).aspx